# Cannot get @CssImport to apply only to component scope

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have been wasted hours and days trying to style the Vaadin Upload component.  The goal is simple:

- sometimes I need the component to show the uploaded file using its built-in file list with allows delete.
- other times, I want to hide this list because I have another component such as Grid to show the file details.

Now comes the problem, I can never get it to consistently work using @CssImport with themeFor=vaadin-upload and themeFor=vaadin-upload-file.  Vaadin seems to compile the shadow dom and the final result varies, it mixes up the two options and whichever comes last gets applied.

I then thought maybe because the @CssImport is in the @Route component.  So, I created two custom upload components that extended the vaadin-upload component with the difference being the different @CssImport (see below).  That (frustratingly) still doesn't work. I inspect the document and found that the  inside the shadow-dom contains both even though I never use both on the same page.

```
@CssImport(value = "./css/vaadin-upload-show.css", themeFor = "vaadin-upload")
public class UploadShowFiles extends Upload {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9198630843136885092L;

    public UploadShowFiles(Receiver receiver) {
        super(receiver);
    }

}

@CssImport(value = "./css/vaadin-upload-hidefile.css", themeFor = "vaadin-upload")
public class UploadHideFiles extends Upload {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2344860066834705807L;

    public UploadHideFiles(Receiver receiver) {
        super(receiver);
        setClassName("hide-upload");
    }

}
```

The css below will appear in the shadow dom.  I expect only display: none or otherwise, not both.

```
[name="file-list"] {
    display: none !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}

[name="file-list"] div[part="file-list"] {
    display: none !important;
}

[name="file-list"] {
    display: block !important;
    height: 1.5rem !important;
}

[name="file-list"] div[part="file-list"] {
    display: block !important;
}
```

p/s: This is my first experience using Vaadin in a project and I probably never going to use it again.  Customizing anything in Vaadin is so time-consuming and painful.

Comment: "Customizing anything in Vaadin is so time-consuming and painful." That's my first impression, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styling in the shadow DOM can indeed be tricky. The [simplified theming](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme) in Vaadin 19 helps a bit.

Where the `@CssImport` annotation is placed affects if the CSS should be included in the document, but not which components it affects. With `themeFor`, it will always be applied to all matching components.

What you can do is to use the `:host` selector to limit which upload components it applies to. Here I am using a class-based approach:

```
:host(.no-file-list) [name="file-list"] {
    display: none !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}

:host(.no-file-list) [name="file-list"] div[part="file-list"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I can then hide the file list in an upload component by adding a class:

```
@Route
@CssImport(value = "./styles/upload-style.css", themeFor = "vaadin-upload")
public class FileUploadTest extends VerticalLayout {

    public FileUploadTest() {
        Upload uploadWithFileList = new Upload();
        Upload uploadWithoutFileList = new Upload();
        uploadWithoutFileList.addClassName("no-file-list");

        add(uploadWithFileList, uploadWithoutFileList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the quickest correct and directly to the point response I got on stackoverflow!